# Google App Engine with Drive API: Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

My application is catching this exception a lot of time when updating a file to Drive API.

I first thought that it was reaching the 60 seconds limit of user requests so I moved it in a task (Push queue).

Now, I am still getting this exception so I think this is from somewhere else but can't figure out where.

Thanks for your help.

Below, the full stacktrace:

```
2013-05-07 15:55:20,241 ERROR An error occurred : Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/0B_1TUNLdmniRNlFUY29sUEVSYjg?uploadType=resumable&alt=json&newRevision=true&upload_id=AEnB2UpiEAPY7XedKYn09yFCbN7FhVXhr0jXKvph9zLxdsenkM8muO7oX4VIECcgfAA3QDeUNUXXGVjOl1ScJy6elAn7TrATHw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~unishared-gae/production.367146605343225296/main.py", line 720, in post
    content, data['mimeType'], resumable=True)
  File "lib/oauth2client/util.py", line 128, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "lib/apiclient/http.py", line 657, in execute
    _, body = self.next_chunk(http=http)
  File "lib/oauth2client/util.py", line 128, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "lib/apiclient/http.py", line 798, in next_chunk
    headers=headers)
  File "lib/oauth2client/util.py", line 128, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "lib/oauth2client/client.py", line 490, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1570, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1317, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1286, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 500, in getresponse
    raise HTTPException(str(e))
```

Comment: The error is still thrown during the file upload.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you give me more info about that? Shoud I always catch HttpException when uplodading? I'm a little bit confused by your answer.

Comment: Can you give me more details about that Burcu please? Thanks!

Comment: When you try with a small file, is there a deadline occurring?

Comment: It occurs also on small file (I've just checked one of ~ 60 bytes)

Comment: In addition it seems that errors are mainly occurring on Google Apps for Education accounts.

Comment: After looking deeper in our logs I've remarked that this kind of exception is raised on multiple endpoints (not only uploading) like permissions, oauth2/token, discovery, etc. What should we do to properly handle them?